Why does the contingency of a future disjunction make it unable to entail the same statement's current individal propositions?
I'm new to philosophy and I read that Boethius said that the disjunction of "either there will be a sea battle tomorrow or not" does not make these individual propositions necessarily true today: "there will be a sea battle tomorrow" or "there will not be a sea battle tomorrow". I had a little bit of a conversation with ChatGPT on this and I think it gave pretty good explanations but I'd still like to ask here. Here is ChatGPT's response: https://justpaste.it/1kxpe

Boethius' argument is essentially modern intuitionistic logic theory's argument against classic logic which doesn't satisfy the disjunction property, that is, whenever a sentence A∨B is a theorem then either A is a theorem or B is a theorem...

This isn't necessarily a time/temporal issue, it's just the nature of a disjunction:
"A or not A" is a tautology in classical logic (necessarily true).
However, we only need "A" or "not A" to make "A or not A" true, hence cannot conclude "A" nor can we conclude "not A".
The temporal aspect is interesting in that we know one of the two must happen tomorrow, but since we don't know today, we may not be able to assign either of them a truth value today -- this depends critically on what viewpoint we are taking: a view from today or a view from nowhere. Since when tomorrow comes each will have a truth value, propositoinal logic would use those truth values, whereas other types of logic may insist we don't know till tomorrow.
Under a supervaluationist viewpoint, "There will be a sea battle tomorrow or there will not be a sea battle tomorrow" is super-true (true under all assignments of truth values to the individual propositions) whereas neither of them is super-true (nor super-false).
A branch of logic called "temporal logic" was developed to handle temporal arguments much more naturally.

Boethius is actually relating an example given by Aristotle in De Interpretatione. Many commentators take Aristotle to be saying:

The law of excluded middle holds. There will be a sea battle tomorrow or there won't.
Bivalence does not hold. It is not the case that it is either true that there will be a sea battle tomorrow or false that there will be a sea battle tomorrow.

On this interpretation, Aristotle and Boethius allow that future contingents are neither true nor false. Such statements don't have a truth value until the events actually come to pass or not.
This is not the only way to understand the situation. We could perhaps say that, "There will be a sea battle tomorrow" is true or false, we just don't yet know which. Using this approach we might say:

S ∨ ¬S

The sea battle happens or it doesn't.

¬(KS ∨ K¬S)

It's not the case that: I know the sea battle happens or I know that it doesn't.
To speak of 'knowing' is rather weak, since 4 might just be a statement of ignorance. Maybe the sea battle has already happened but I haven't heard news of the result. So, instead of 'knowing' we could introduce a modal notion such as, "It is determinately the case at time t that...". We might then write something like:

¬(□S ∨ □¬S)

Where □ indicates the modality of a proposition having a determinate value at some earlier time.
Kneale and Kneale (1) interpret Aristotle to be holding the first position but say that this is an error. Aristotle is mistakenly confusing a sentence type with the proposition expressed by a sentence token. Doing this leads in turn to the error of supposing that saying of a sentence about the future that it is true or false implies determinism. Aristotle is concerned to deny determinism about the future, but we do not need to abandon bivalence to do this.
(1) W. Kneale and M. Kneale, The Development of Logic, (Oxford, 1962), Chapter II, section 4, Aristotle's Theory of Meaning and Truth.
